# how to find the ip address of client who is login to our website or browsing our website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, ip-address

Here i have a small problem, that i want to find out the IP Address of the client who is accessing my website, i tried so many but all these are giving me 127.0.0.1 as IP, while i am testing in local host,

Please some one provide the code snippet and help me,

Thanks in advance,

```
 public string GetClientIP()
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    string ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
    {
        string[] ipRange = ip.Split(',');
        int le = ipRange.Length - 1;
        result = ipRange[0];
    }
    else
    {
        result = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: your localhost's IP address is 12.0.0.1 if you deploy it live and go though different IP you will be able to see correct IP.

Comment: When you are testing as localhost, your IP will always be 127.0.0.1. You need to log the IPs from non-localhost environment (UAT/Prod/etc.).

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is your home / local address!

Comment: Well 127.0.0.1 is a local host IP so can I wager a guess and say you are not going to be able to test this function until its accessable from an external port?

Comment: Note also that people visiting your site through a proxy will have the same public IP, so depending on what you intend to do, IP may not be enough to target 1 specific people.

Comment: Thanks for reply me, If IP is not enough to target to a particular machine or a people, how can i do the same?

Comment: Ya, you are right when i run this on local host it given me 127.0.0.1 but when i host it on server and run it is giving me the correct ip, Thank you,

Comment: Hi Bartdude, If IP is not enough to target to a particular machine or a people, how can i do the same, can i do this in any other way?

Answer (score 1):

This is to be expected, your localhost IP address will most of the time be 127.0.0.1.

As said in the comments, when you will deploy your site and remote clients access it, their actual IP will correctly be retrieved.

If you want to try locally, you can try to configure your local network so that a remote computer on the same network access your web site. There you should see the IP address of that computer (for instance: 192.168.x.x).